# Possible to extract a List from a Dictionary of Lists in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I understand that using .values() will pull the values out of the dictionary into a list, but im curious if it is possible to pull the second item (for instance) out of the lists in a dictionary without a loop.

for example:

```
dictionary1={
             fish : [1, 2, 3],
             dog :  [9, 5, 8],
             cat :  [4, 4, 4]
             }
```

I would like to extract the list:

```
[3, 8, 4]
```

Just curious if there is a cleaner way than looping, Thanks!

Comment: You can't avoid looping, and there is nothing dirty about looping.

Comment: Burhan: Understood. It looks like these guys loops are quite a bit cleaner than min though... im glad i asked :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
>>> [v[2] for v in dictionary1.values()]
[3, 8, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be putting the keys in single/double quotes in dictionary.Try this.

```
d1 = {
             "fish" : [1, 2, 3],
             "dog" :  [9, 5, 8],
             "cat" :  [4, 4, 4]
             }
print [x[-1] for x in d1.values()]
```

Comment: yes quotes; i should get in the habit of running my examples before i post them ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In your question (if I am correct), you are basically creating a 2D array from dictionary values and then trying to get a particular column of that 2D array. If so you can easily do that using a python package `numpy`, documentation of the package is available [here](http://www.numpy.org/),

I think following code will help you get started,

```
import numpy

dictionary1=dict(
             fish = [1, 2, 3],
             dog =  [9, 5, 8],
             cat =  [4, 4, 4]
             )

numpy_array = numpy.array(dictionary1.values())
column_number = 2

print numpy_array[:,column_number]
```

Comment: Good to know. Ill probably use the other implementation for now, but its good to know numpy can do that for more complex things in the future.